# React Router version 6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-router-dom

I am having problems with React Router version 6. The error is Uncaught Error: `[PeopleContainer]` is not a  component. All component children of  must be a  or `<React.Fragment>`

The App.js Component

```
import './App.css';
import PeopleContainer from './PeopleContainer';
import { BrowserRouter, Link, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import PeopleList from './PeopleList';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
          <BrowserRouter>  
            <Routes>
              <Route path="/people"><PeopleContainer/></Route>
              <Link to="/people">People</Link>
            </Routes>
          </BrowserRouter>  
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
PeopleContainer.js

import React from 'react'
import Media from 'react-media'
import { Navigate, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import PeopleList from './PeopleList';
import Person from './Person';
import people from './people.json'

const PeopleContainer = () => {
  return (
    <Media queries={{
        small: "(max-width: 700px)",
    }}>
    { (size) => size. Small ? ( 
       <Routes>
          <Route path='/people/:id'> <Person/></Route>
          <PeopleList/>
        </Routes>  )
    :   (
    <div style={{display: 'flex'}}>
       <PeopleList />
       <Routes>
          <Route path='/people/:id'><Person/></Route>
          <Navigate to={`/people/${people[0].id}`}/>
       </Routes>
    </div>
    )  
}
    </Media>
  )
}

export default PeopleContainer
```

```
PeopleList.js

import React from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import people from './people.json';
import './PeopleList.css'

const PeopleList = () => {
  return (
    <nav className='PeopleList' >
        <ul>
            {people. Map((person)=>(
                <li key={`person-${person.id}`}>
                    <NavLink activeClassName ="currentPerson"
                     to={`/people/${person.id}`}>{person.name}</NavLink>   
                </li>
            ))}
        </ul>
    </nav>
  )
}

export default PeopleList
```

```
Person.js

import React from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import people from './people.json';
import './Person.css';

const Person = () => {
  
  const { id } = useParams();
  const person = people.filter((p) => p.id === id)[0];

  return ( 
    <main className = "Person">
      <h1>{person.name}</h1>
      <label>ID:</label>
      <div className='Person-id'>{id}</div>
      <label>Address:</label>
      <div className='Person-address'>{person.address}</div>
      <label>Department:</label>
      <div className='Person-department'>{person.department}</div>
    </main>
  )
}

export default Person
```

The people data

```
[
    {
      "id": "58826508",
      "name": "Kip Russel",
      "address": "18627 Sporer Mews\nMaximechester\nSouth Dakota\n04691",
      "department": "Movies"
    },
    {
      "id": "34033353",
      "name": "Harrison Swift",
      "address": "910 Lueilwitz Lake\nLake Troy\nWisconsin\n25072",
      "department": "Games"
    },
    {
      "id": "28977789",
      "name": "Carter Heaney",
      "address": "1095 Johnny Ridge\nLynchstad\nIowa\n81452-3853",
      "department": "Clothing"
    },
    {
      "id": "62734836",
      "name": "Evert Conroy",
      "address": "812 Dario Drive\nMurrayville\nIllinois\n51582",
      "department": "Games"
    },
    {
      "id": "31034282",
      "name": "Hoyt Kautzer",
      "address": "398 Wunsch Course\nPort Edwardo\nMaryland\n40326",
      "department": "Jewelery"
    },
```

```
    {
      "id": "43936107",
      "name": "Miles Kerluke",
      "address": "8620 Gerhold Ford\nRogahnburgh\nMississippi\n72312",
      "department": "Shoes"
    },
    {
      "id": "61453579",
      "name": "Tiara Stoltenberg",
      "address": "42719 Sally Stream\nGeorgiannaport\nOregon\n51799-8713",
      "department": "Beauty"
    },
```

```
    {
      "id": "65974385",
      "name": "Dovie Terry",
      "address": "07231 Schamberger Turnpike\nNew Augustine\nNew Mexico\n654
      "department": "Books"
    }]
```

I don't know what is happening to my code as I am new to react router. This is the code I copy from the textbook. I think they are using version 5

Comment: manage space between component name and closing tag  `<Route path="/people"><PeopleContainer /></Route>` or if it not work replace it with `<Route exact path="/people" component={PeopleContainer} />`.

Answer (score 1):

In React Router version 6, you cannot pass children props other than **`<Route>` or `<React.Fragment>`** inside **`<Routes>`**. In your App.js component change **`<Routes>...</Routes>`** part with this

```
<BrowserRouter>  
    <Routes>
        <Route path="/people" element={<PeopleContainer/>} />
        {/* <Link to="/people">People</Link> <--- remove this */}
    </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

and change your `<Routes>` implementation like above on all components that use `<Routes>`